# Ansible and docker: locally build image get pulled and causes failure

Tags: linux, unix, docker, ansible

I'm using Ansible to provision my server with anything required to make a my website work. The goal is to install a base system and provide it with docker containers running apps (at the moment it's just one app).

The problem I'm facing is that my docker image isn't hosted at dockerhub or something else. Instead it's being built by an Ansible task. However, when I'm trying to run the built image, Ansible tries to pull it (which isn't possible) and then dies.

This is what the playbook section looks like:

```
- name: check or build image
  docker_image:
    path=/srv/svenv.nl-docker
    name='svenv/svenv.nl'
    state=build

- name: start svenv/svenv.nl container
  docker:
    name: svenv.nl
    volumes:
    - /srv/svenv.nl-docker/data/var/lib/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/
    - /srv/svenv.nl-docker/data/svenv.nl/svenv/media:/svenv.nl/svenv/media
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 3306:3306
    image: svenv/svenv.nl
```

When I run this, a failure indicates that the svenv/svenv.nl get's pulled from the repository, it isn't there so it crashes:

```
failed: [vps02.svenv.nl] => {"changes": ["{\"status\":\"Pulling repository svenv/svenv.nl\"}\r\n", "{\"errorDetail\":{\"message\":\"Error: image svenv/svenv.nl:latest not found\"},\"error\":\"Error: image svenv/svenv.nl:latest not found\"}\r\n"], "failed": true, "status": ""}
msg: Unrecognized status from pull.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

My question is:

How can I

- Build a local docker
- Then start it as a container without pulling it

Comment: What version of ansible are you using? What version of docker?  Your playbook works fine for me as written, assuming that I replace all the pathnames with something available locally.

Comment: - ansible version (on local machine): ansible 1.9.2
- docker version (on remote): Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using docker 1.6.0 locally.  Let me see what happens with the newer version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are hitting this error:

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/1707

Ansible is attempting to create a container, but the create is failing with:

```
docker.errors.InvalidVersion: mem_limit has been moved to host_config in API version 1.19
```

Unfortunately, there is catch-all `except:` that is hiding this error.  The result is that rather than failing with the above message, ansible assumes that the image is simply missing locally and attempts to pull it.

You can work around this by setting `docker_api_version` to something earlier than 1.19:

```
- name: start svenv/svenv.nl container
  docker:
    name: svenv.nl
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 3306:3306
    image: svenv/svenv.nl
    docker_api_version: 1.18
```

Comment: Many, many thanks. This solved the issue for me. I was already falling back to the docker's repo bash scripts with nasty workarounds. This cleans up my Ansible.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer to mark it as accepted, which is both a way of saying thanks and also lets other folks know that this question has been addressed.  It looks like there is a patch for this issue but it's not current; I'm seeing how much effort is involved in getting applied against the current code.

Comment: I just helped merge [a patch](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/1744) that seems to fix this issue.